# Как проверить, что список содержит слово?

Tags: c#

У меня есть список. В нем элементы вида: "_something":"",

Так вот, я хотела бы узнать, как сделать поиск по списку так, чтобы, имея только something без ковычек и нижнего подчеркивания, находить индекс элемента. Исходя из того, есть ли something внутри, мне нужно будет осуществлять разные действия.

List.Contains, как я поняла, не подходит, List.Where тоже, List.Exists кажется тоже не работает, либо я не смогла правильно выразить условия. Всем спасибо за помощь!

С помощью 
List fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(filesList[i]).ToList();
я собираю все строки из JSON, как на скрине, затем из БД я вытаскиваю новую таблицу, если ее название уже присутствует внутри списка, я только проверяю все ли ключи там есть, если нет, то добавляю тех, которых нет. Если названия таблицы нет, соответственно, добавляю в конец файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `элементы вида: "_something":""` - не json вы случаем пытаетесь костыльно прочитать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да-да, именно его. Но я прохожу стажировку и мне сказали работать с JSON, как с обычным текстовым документом

Comment: Ужас! Хорошо, а лист какой тип имеет, string?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да. Сейчас правлю вопрос, чтобы легче было понять.

Comment: Ужас! Проверять навыки нужно на реальных задачах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну допустим, есть коллекция:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
    "_something1\":\"",
    "_something2\":\"",
    "_something3\":\"",
    "_something4\":\"",
    "_something5\":\""
};
```

Имеем только `something4`. Нам надо найти элемент, который это содержит:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("something4"));
```

Если нам надо получить номер элемента в коллекции, то обернуть все в `IndexOf` и получить что то вроде этого:

```
var index = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("something4")));
```

Comment: @Nataila `FirstOrDefault` вернет вам `NULL`, если элемент не найден. А если не найдет `IndexOf` - значением будет `-1`.

Comment: Я поняла, спасибо вам :)

Comment: @Nataila `FirstOrDefault` по сути возвращает нам тот же тип, что лежит в коллекции (string, int, bool, class и др.), если значение не найдено, то будет установлено [значение по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) данного типа.

Comment: спасибо еще раз :) Теперь все точно понятно.

Comment: @Nataila Да не за что. Рад, что смог помочь. Ну а вообще, стоит вашим "преподавателям" по шеям надавать за такое...

Comment: на самом деле у меня большой объект динамичный. У компании есть в библиотеке функция, которая этот объект может де(сесериализовать). Но там какая-то проблема, поэтому сказали делать так